# run controller before rendering html ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, HTML is rendered before controller completely runs. I want index method in controller to first run completely before rendering HTML. 
I was able to achieve this by adding <% sleep(x) %> at the beginning of the HTML page but i want to do it without using it.
can anyone suggest a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste def index action code

Comment: Erm, do you mean you want the action method on your controller to do something after it's rendered the page?

Comment: no i want index method to execute before rendering the pagedef index
  @data=Csvtest.all
  @length=@data.length-1
  @resp=[]
  threads = (0..@length-1).map do |i|  #services are pinged concurrently
        Thread.new(i) do |i|
            @resp[i]=%x{curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" #{@data[i]['url']} -o /dev/null}.to_i  #@response contains status code
        end
     end    
 end

Comment: sry about indentation

Comment: i want this method to finish before rendering the page

Comment: i am using @resp in my html page and it using nil value

Comment: You can't do this.  The page is rendered INSIDE the action: that's what the action does - it runs a bit of code (the code you can see in your action) and then renders the page.  The rendering happens inside the action.  I think you need to take a step back and explain why you want to do this.

Comment: U r making curl request in controller. Better do it via ajax (after rendering page) and show loader till response comes.

Comment: @Neeraj It depends on the endpoint of his curl, if it is not on his current domain. There is a problem with cross-origin policy in the ajax call. You can find more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment above you are using this index action:

```
def index 
  @data=Csvtest.all
  @length=@data.length-1 
  @resp=[] 
  threads = (0..@length-1).map do |i| #services are pinged concurrently 
    Thread.new(i) do |i| 
      @resp[i] = %x{curl -sL -w "%{http_code}" #{@data[i]['url']} -o /dev/null}.to_i #@response contains status code 
    end 
  end 
end
```

You are forgetting to say main thread to wait before all other threads terminates. You should call

```
threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

It tells, main thread wait until all of concurrent threads will pass to the end and than continue.